# How to give sum statement conditions in a case statement?

Tags: sql-server

I want to use the sum function in the ELSE part of the CASE Statement. I need to give the SUM function conditions but I'm unable to do so.

I tried to use the GROUP BY Function within the sum function but it doesn't work.

```
CASE WHEN SectionCrossList = NULL THEN InstructorCredits ELSE InstructorCredits/Sum(Instructorcredits) GROUP BY (AcademicYear,SectionCrossList) END NumCreditSplit
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 220 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'. 
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 221 Incorrect syntax near 'NumCreditSplit'.

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table structure, some sample data, and the result you're trying to get for that sample.

Comment: `GROUP BY` goes after your `FROM` and before your `ORDER BY` (or before the `HAVING` if there is one); not in the middle of a column expression. Sample data and expected result (as `text` or DDL and DML statements) will greatly help us help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com//sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or window function [sum](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AcademicYear,SectionCrossList,
        CASE 
            WHEN SectionCrossList = NULL 
            THEN 
                InstructorCredits 
            ELSE 
                InstructorCredits/Sum(Instructorcredits)
            end NumCreditSplit
     FROM <yourTable>
     group by AcademicYear,SectionCrossList
```